# DOJO 1.9. FilteringSelect ComboBox scroll to last selected item on show [IE]

Tags: dojo

How to make dropdown scroll to the last selected option after dropdown is re-opened?

Calling `filtering_select_ref.dropdown.set('selected', selected_node_ref)` or `filtering_select_ref.set('scrollOnFocus', true)` did not work for me on IE 11.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to scroll to the option, you could use win.scrollIntoView(node_ref) from "dojo/window" module as shown in the [docs](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/window/scrollIntoView.html) and pass the id or the node reference to the option as an argument.

You may also find these methods interesting to help solve your problem:

```
filtering_select_ref.openDropDown()
var dropdown = filtering_select_ref.dropdown;
dropdown.selectFirstNode()
dropdown.selectNextNode()
dropdown.selectPreviousNode()
dropdown.selectLastNode()
```

Comment: Was thinking about `scrollIntoView` but attached onShow handler never got called...

Answer (score 1):

@Carlos Nantes suggested good options however I was aware of them and my problem with them was that I could not "catch" the moment when dropdown got opened.

I finally found a way to "catch" that moment with `filtering_select_ref.watch('_opened', function()...`

[watch doc can be found here](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/form/ComboBox#1_9dijit_form_ComboBox_watch)